# Re-setting select field to default on form submit using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

I have a form created using AngularJS. The form is a questionnaire type form that can be submitted multiple times in a row. The form is a mix of text areas and drop-down select fields.

The form has quite a few number of questions and they need to be reset to default each time the form is submitted.

I manage to clear the text areas using ***$setPristine()*** but the drop-down fields dont rest to default values - they stay as previously selected when the form is submitted and you then revisit the form again. How do I reset all fields on the form - including the drop-down *select*? I dont want to reset each field individually because, as I mentioned, there can be a large number of questions per form and it would be inefficient to manually reset each question.

Below is a small sample of my form **view**

```
<div ng-controller="FormController" data-ng-init="init()">
    <ons-page>
        <!-- Form Start -->
            <form class="questionnaire-form" name="myForm" novalidate>
                <section class="form-section">
                    <ons-row>
                        <ons-col>
                            <p class="form-header">Header 1</p>
                        </ons-col>
                    </ons-row>
                    <ons-row>
                        <ons-col>
                            <p class="form-field-text">
                                <span style="color: #f76327">*</span> Outcome
                            </p>
                        </ons-col>
                    </ons-row>
                    <ons-row>
                        <ons-col width="90%">
                            <select id="outcome" name="outcome"
                                    ng-model="severity.desc"
                                    ng-options="severityOption.desc as severityOption.desc for severityOption in severity"
                                    ng-change="changedValue(severity.desc, 'Severity')">
                                <option value="" label="-- Please Select --"></option>
                            </select>
                        </ons-col>
                    </ons-row>

                    <ons-row>
                        <ons-col>
                            <p class="form-field-text">
                                <span style="color: #f76327">*</span> PICW
                            </p>
                        </ons-col>
                    </ons-row>
                    <ons-row ng-hide="toggle">
                        <ons-col width="90%">
                            <textarea class="textarea"
                                      rows="1"
                                      placeholder="PICW"
                                      ng-model="picw"></textarea>
                        </ons-col>
                    </ons-row>
                </section>

                <section var="saveBtn" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</ons-button>
                </section>
            </form>
        </ons-scroller>
    </ons-page>
</div>
```

My controller handles the values being submitted by the user and works as intended. Then when the user submits the form I fire the submit() function that sends the data to the server and sets the for to ***pristine***. However, the drop-down select values arent reset.

My views **controller**

```
var formController = angular.module("formController ", []);
formController .controller("FormController", function ($scope, FormField) {
    var init = function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    };

    init();

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Set severity drop down value
        $scope.severity = FormField.getSeverity();
    };

    // Save details to database
    $scope.submitForm= function () {
        // Do form submit action here

        // Set form pristine
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    };
});
```

And I would create the values for the form drop-down select as follows.

```
var formFields = angular.module("formField", []);
formFields.service("FormField", function () {
    // Severity
    var Severity = [ {
        desc: "Insignificant", id: "0"
    }, {
        desc: "Minor", id: "1"
    },{
        desc: "Moderate", id: "2"
    }, {
        desc: "Major", id: "3"
    }, {
        desc: "Catastrophic", id: "4"
    }];

    return {
        // Get severity
        getSeverity: function () {
            return Severity;
        },
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of the `scope severity` into a `variable original`.

Then, while resetting set `$scope.severity` to that `original variable`

`$scope.severity= angular.copy($scope.original);` this reset the form to the old data.

**Here is the code:**

```
var formController = angular.module("formController ", []);
formController .controller("FormController", function ($scope, FormField) {
    var init = function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    };

    init();

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Set severity drop down value
        $scope.severity = FormField.getSeverity();
        $scope.original = $scope.severity;
    };

    // Save details to database
    $scope.submitForm= function () {
        // Do form submit action here

        // Set form pristine
        $scope.severity= angular.copy($scope.original);
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It still displays the last select in the drop-down list once the form has been submitted and the updated code is fired.

Comment: try.  `$scope.severity= $scope.original;` and check, even if didn't work, make  `$scope.severity = {}` and check whether it is reflecting?